# NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite! That's illegal. constant:inf

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, lldb

After iOS update version 10.3.3, a bug appeared in some devices, not all. that is..

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:inf firstAnchor:<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608000679c80 "_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fce8d57aee0.right"> secondAnchor:<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x608000679d00 "UILayoutGuide:0x6080001be680'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.right">'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e3126b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000114a67f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110e36402 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000111a5b749 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001119df92c -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] + 629
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001119df689 -[NSLayoutConstraint setConstant:] + 68
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000112a6dc52 -[UIView _updateLayoutMarginsGuideConstraintsIfNecessary] + 358
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000112a6de5e -[UIView _layoutMarginsDidChangeFromOldMargins:] + 194
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000112a6e849 -[UIView _updateInferredLayoutMarginsFromSuperview:] + 850
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000112a6fc03 -[UIView setSafeAreaInsets:] + 446
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000112a6f2a5 -[UIView _updateSafeAreaInsets] + 125
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000112a9c30e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1571
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000112adc343 -[UINavigationBar layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 178
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000011264cc92 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112650d79 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001125d9851 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 385
    16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001126051c2 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112605f14 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 76
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110dd3e57 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110dd3dae __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110db83c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110db7b29 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011a8dd9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001129ce9a4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  APP NAME                            0x000000010f8c1847 main + 55
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117f8d621 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Funny thing is that this error doesn't make any sense to all the equipment. There was no error in my device (iOS 10.3.3)

so I tried running this app in Xcode 9 beta 5, iOS 11 beta 5 to get some error and appeared this assertion failure. I think There is a doubt about navigationBarItem.

Please help.

Comment: There's differences between iOS11 and previous versions. Things get deprecated. Here's two links that may help: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/ and https://useyourloaf.com/blog/changing-root-view-layout-margins/ I'm betting it's one of these. Reason it out: (1) It works in iOS 10.3.3, which implies you were using Xcode 8. (2) It doesn't work in iOS 11 / Xcode 9 beta 5. Good luck!

Comment: thanks dfd. I'll see all that links. but, I saw this error in my coworker's iPhone 7 (iOS 10.3.3).. so, I'm very confused ..

Comment: My advice? Go at this logically. Separate the "beta" (iOS11, Xcode9) from the "current". Eliminate what works! Then, narrow down - if it's iOS11, use Xcode 9 and it's simulator, which are very stable, to duplicate if not also see if anything works. Next, debug by using breakpoints. **Bottom line?** If you are confused, you are allowing too many variables to intrude into your *real* issue. (And also, it gets invades into your question more than it should.) **Narrow things down!** And please, just because you get this error on your co-worker's phone, doesn't mean anything! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much dfd. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting an "infinite" origin for a valid UITextRange when trying to get UITextField.firstRect(). That was causing the constraint update to fail.

I would recommend to get Xcode 9 and debug your code there.